# Get confused between $d\overrightarrow{A}$ and $dA$. Can you elucidate the difference?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm studying multivariable calculus.
I came across these a lot but always wondered what the differece is exactly.

My guess is $dA$ means only the surface while $d\overrightarrow{A}$ means vectors perpendicularly pointing out from the surface.

Comment: Generally if you're working in 3 dimensions, $\vec{dA}$ means $\hat{n}dA$ where $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal to the infinitesimal area $dA$.